# ggplot2 ecdf behaviour seems odd

Tags: r, ggplot2, ecdf

Consider the following series and cumulative plot:

```
x=c(0,0,0,0.5,10,1500)
qplot(x,geom='step',stat='ecdf')
```

This produces a graph that starts left of zero. In other words, it looks as if x has negative values. At the right it continues to the right after reaching 1500 and 100%. So, it looks as if there are x points larger than 1500.

I get what I expect when doing the whole thing manually:

```
xs=sort(x)   
qplot(xs,1:length(xs)/length(xs),x,geom='step')
```

But this seems to defy the whole purpose of the `stat='ecdf'` shortcut.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

By default `stat_ecdf` will pad the endpoints by `max(0.08 * diff(rx), median(diff(xvals)))`.  In my answer to [In R ggplot2, include stat_ecdf() endpoints (0,0) and (1,1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609547/in-r-ggplot2-include-stat-ecdf-endpoints-0-0-and-1-1/31835958#31835958) I give a way of working around this, but it might be a little drastic, depending on your use case.